# C# How to validate null optional array parameter in REST API?

Tags: c#, api, rest, data-annotations

Imagine that I have an endpoint that accepts optional `MyParam` **string array** attribute.
How to check it if it's null or empty with most basic way - Data Annotations would be the best.

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?MyParam=`

- `[Required]` is not an option as parameter has to be optional
- `[StringLength]` with MinimumLength doesn't work
- `[MinLength]` doesn't work at all
- `[RegularExpression(@"\S+")]` doesn't work at all

**Update:**
I want to do it on string array not just string, sorry about confusion. Hope this help to justify why above DataAnnotations don't work.

Comment: and what's the use of this Desired DataAnnotation, how would you use it?

Comment: It should simply return error when the param is empty or null.

Comment: You can mark it as `[Required]` and Check if `ModelState.IsValid()`, if its not return an error from the controller.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Parameter has to be optional, `IsValid()` just checks if it was provided or not - still can accept empty string.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking at here is a custom model validation attribute.

For example:

```cs
public class MyParamValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyParamAttribute(string param)
    {
        Param = param;
    }

    public string Param { get; }

    public string GetErrorMessage() =>
        $"Invalid param value {param}.";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var myParam = (string)value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myParam))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes-1

Comment: I have also updated my question to justify why other DataAnnotations don't work - I mean string array attribute, not just string, still your answer looks valid with minor editing.